# Divide all elements of ideal with polynomial in Macaulay 2?

Tags: math, macaulay2

[image]

On computing basis of ideal quotient (Ideal, Varities, and Algorithms p.197, 3rd edition), one needs to divide ideal with a polynomial. How can you do it in Macaulay 2?

Comment: Why downvote? Please let me know to make it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Emanuele who would use substitution command such as below. For algorithms such as computing the quotient ideal, please note that each term must be divisible by x like the example.

[image]